# Crashlytics Initialization ConnectionException (EHOSTUNREACH)

Tags: android, crashlytics, okhttp, twitter-fabric, httpexception

I have the Crashlytics SDK installed on an Android app (through Fabric) and it was working perfectly before. All of a sudden, I'm getting ConnectionExceptions and Crashlytics cannot communicate with its remote server.

Fabric is instantiated at the end of onCreate in my Application class:

```
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  ...
  Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}
```

Here is the stacktrace on app bootup. Any thoughts?

```
06-18 16:53:57.560  15388-15388/? I/Fabric﹕ Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.2.56
06-18 16:54:00.759  15388-15417/com.myapp E/Fabric﹕ Unknown error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until settings can be retrieved.
    io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/54.83.37.39 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1409)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:96)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:83)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:80)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:64)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:156)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:123)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/54.83.37.39 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:238)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1407)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:96)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:83)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:80)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:64)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:156)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:123)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1407)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:96)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:83)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:80)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:64)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:156)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:123)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. The errors only seem to happen when I'm using my local Second Cup wifi network. When I use my home network, it works just fine.

There must be some sort of proxy issue going on here.